# how can i use Icon Image in AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use an image as an icon on the left of AppBar(title) [image][image]

when I do it this is what happens in the emulator

Comment: could you provide what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you add `avatar1.png` in `assets/images` folder and also add
below line in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and this is how I solved it `icon: Image.assets('images/avatar1.png')`

Comment: Not 'Image.assets()', but Image.asset()

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because the size of the image

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).